# Google Adsense Error "TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0 "

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using responsive Google Ads on my website but unfortunately it is not working all the time and most of time it is returning

> TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0

I tried to fix the issue by defining the Ad Sizes but still the issue is not resolved yet.

```
.adslot_1 { width: 320px; height: 100px; }
@media (min-width:500px) { .adslot_1 { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
@media (min-width:800px) { .adslot_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
@media only screen and (min-width:800px)and (max-width:3000px) {
    #topbanner {
        width: 640px;
        height: 90px;
    }
}
```

Well, this is the actual Google Adsense Google Code that I've used (for security reasons I've remove pub-id and ad-slot.)

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- articles(auto) -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1"
     style="display:inline-block;"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-[MY_AD_ID]"
     data-ad-slot="AD_SLOT_NOS"
     data-ad-format="rectangle, horizontal"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: I got this problem when I put the adsense code block inside an Angular ng-cloak, the problem has gone after I moved the code block out of ng-cloak. If you put the adsense code inside some dynamic generated html, make sure DOM is ready and visible before the google code is executed.

Comment: This error happens when the parent container doesn't have a valid width  a) due to CSS positioning like absolute or float.OR b) it is hidden with display:none. For this you need to make use of Officially approved code change. 1) Remove the advance responsive tag format attribute, and 2) set the width & height for INS tag. [GOOGLE ADSENSE ERROR - NO SLOT SIZE FOR AVAILABLEWIDTH](https://davidsekar.com/website-monetization/google-adsense-error-no-slot-size-for-availablewidth)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I used:

```
window.onload = function() {
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
}
```

My site was loading pages in a special way, making heavy use of AJAX, so it had to be this way. Hope this helps someone.

**EDIT 2018:** I feel like I should mention now that the preferred way to do this would be with `window.addEventListener( 'load', ... )`, instead of the old method of `window.onload = ...`

Comment: it definitely helped.

Comment: This helped me, thank you so much. Our site is using a masonry display, using JS, so the Ad's container was not being calculated properly until I used this! Future readers: please note he replaced the following with that code: (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); <--- Replace this code!

Comment: It's also possible to modify Google's script slightly: 
      <script>
      document.addEventListener('load', () => {  <=add this line
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});");
       "});    <=and this one
      </script>

Comment: It definitely helped, finally I solved this issue, thanks!

Comment: Please can you show the full script with `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});` ? Thanks

Comment: good shot man... tks

Comment: It is not working any more. It says now "All ins elements in the DOM with class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them."

Answer (score 14):

In our case, we had problem displaying two banners but only in Chrome. First banner would not show and it would generate error:

> No slot size for availableWidth=0

The second banner would be displayed OK. The problem was not happening in Safari or Firefox. Trying to fix the problem via CSS didn't help.

We solved the problem by changing the:

```
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})})
```

jQuery is required for above method.

Comment: You need jQuery enabled on your site. If it already is try jQuery(document).ready(function(){(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})})

Comment: Try the answer by Sorin, which doesn't need jQuery. It worked for me:

window.onload = function() {
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
}

Answer (score 12):

You need to remove the others that are not visible, 
how I use (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $analyticsOff = $('.adsbygoogle:hidden');
  var $analyticsOn = $('.adsbygoogle:visible');

  $analyticsOff.each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  $analyticsOn.each(function() {
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

**1.** Make sure that the DOM is ready when pushing the ad.

Vanilla (Modern browsers only)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
});
```

In jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
});
```

In Angular

```
$timeout(function () {
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
});
```

**2.** Make sure the number of ads you have on the page is correct.

- <s>Total number of ads does not exceed google's limit, which is **3** ads per page</s>. Advertising and other paid promotional material added to your pages should not exceed your content, per [Google's new policy](http://wpquads.com/google-adsense-allowed-number-ads/).
- Number of ads pushed to `adsbygoogle` corresponds to the    number of
  ads you have on page.

**3.** For responsive units, add width and height.

[Responsive ad units](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124) need a width and a height specified on the `ins` element. You could do something like this:

```
ins {
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: The maximum 3 ad limit has been lifted by google. Read this:http://wpquads.com/google-adsense-allowed-number-ads/

Comment: Thanks @ReneHermenau. Updated to reflect Google's changes.

Comment: for our situation we use these css suggestions: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124?vid=0-579913848725-1529586782341#hide

Answer (score 7):

I solved it using setTimeout as the issue is that the GA code its not picking the size of the parent on its default loading.

`setTimeout(function(){(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})}, 1000);`

Answer (score 3):

It's been all day that I've tried to find a solution to the error, and I'd like to thank @Emerson Thompson for his solution!

On one environment I'm working in, I depend on the *Ad Inserter Pro for WordPress* plugin. It turns out that the plugin prints the HTML for all the layouts (mobile and desktop). With viewport width as a criterion, it then hides some using CSS.

When `adsbygoogle.js` finds a hidden ad, it throws the `TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0` exception blocking subsequent javascript execution.

Be sure to check your ad visibility before to initialize them.

Answer (score 2):

Where is your parent container? You are supposed to set width and height on the parent I think, not the actual `<ins>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason is that you are styling the div that contains the ad unit using a framework that creates a conflict in size specification. In my case I was using bootstrap styling which messed up my ad display.

```html
<div id="ad1" class="row">
<!-- ad code-->
</div>
```

This did not work. Once I removed it:

```html
<div id="ad1">
<!--ad code-->
</div>
```

it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

just add `style="display:inline-block;width:100%;"`
this is work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and fixed it by removing these.

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occur if have responsive theme and responsive adsense unit. So, if you define the width and height in CSS (not as %), this will solve (at least it solve my issue)

```
#sidebar {
width: width of your ad px;
height: height of your px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `angular-google-adsense`, you need to remove the `ad-format` tag from your adsense html block;

Wrong:

```
<adsense 
ad-client="ca-pub-2427218021515520" 
ad-slot="5093178896" 
inline-style="display:inline-block;width:100%;" 
ad-format="auto">
```

Right:

```
<adsense 
ad-client="ca-pub-2427218021515520" 
ad-slot="5093178896" 
inline-style="display:inline-block;width:100%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found modifying the ins tag to remove the data-ad-format attribute solved the error for me:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle adslot_1"
 style="display:inline-block;"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-[MY_AD_ID]"
 data-ad-slot="AD_SLOT_NOS"></ins>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, as there is no sidebar on the homepage and the error only appears on it I corrected by adding this on adsense elements in the sidebar

> cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'