# adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0

Tags: adsense

I'm getting this error and some of my ads are not showing. My site use WP with the Ad Inserter Plugin. The creator said that it has nothing to do with the plugin. So I dug up some solutions that I tried to no avail.

This is the error I get:

```
"TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0
    at Di (https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:17:6613)
    at Ci (https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:17:5861)
    at Ri (https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:17:11763)
    at Ej (https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:17:25857)
    at Mj (https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:17:28363)
    at Lj (https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:17:28255)
    at Uj (https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:17:33399)
    at https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:17:31821
    at Pd (https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1:20983)
    at Xd (https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1:23479)"
```

It seems that only the square ads with fixed size (336x280) are returning the error. All the other ads are responsive and showing correctly.

This is what I've tried with no success.

1. Make sure that the DOM is ready when pushing the ad.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
   });
   ```
2. Setting a timeout

   ```
   setTimeout(function(){(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})}, 1000);
   ```
3. Removing the code below from all ads and add it to the header one time

   ```
   <script>
   (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
   </script>
   ```
4. Removing the data-ad-format on all ads
5. Remove other ads that are not visible from the code with this script

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var $analyticsOff = $('.adsbygoogle:hidden');
     var $analyticsOn = $('.adsbygoogle:visible');

     $analyticsOff.each(function() {
       $(this).remove();
     });
     $analyticsOn.each(function() {
       (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
     });
   });
   ```

What am I doing wrong as at least one of these solutions seems to have solved the same issue for many people?

Can someone help me with this, please?

Thank you,

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465168/google-adsense-error-tagerror-adsbygoogle-push-error-no-slot-size-for-avail][1]
That might be of assistance.